# azure architecture - handling  security

Tags: wcf, azure, azure-sql-database, wcf-rest

Planning to migrate our existing application to Azure. 
Our existing architecture with security flow is as follows

- ASP MVC 3.0 UI layer that takes user name password from the user 
  We are planning to migrate the UI layer onto a compute cloud.
  and will be accessible at say uilayerdomainname.com which would have a SSL cert.
- WCF REST webservices layer that amongst other things does authentication as well. This is currently on say servicename.cloudapp.net. (We could map it to servicelayername.com and get a SSL for that domain name as well).
- SQL Azure database

The UI layer sends the credentials to the service layer which authenticates it against the SQL azure database.

Question

- Both the WCF compute cloud and UI Layer are on the same region in Azure. Would the communication between these two be prone to man in the middle attacks? Does my WCF compute cloud need SSL as well? We do have two domain names with SSLs and so could just map the services to one.
- Is there any way I can restrict traffic between the UI layer and the WCF compute cloud - allow only the UI layer to access the services layer?
- Would the performance be better if I publish both the WCF services and UI layer on the same instance? It sort of shoots down the nice layered architecture but if it improves performance I could go with it. We don't want to jump through too many hoops to accomodate the app to Azure lest it becomes difficult to migrate out of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you host your services in a Worker Role, then they can be available only to your Web Role.  You can also host it elsewhere and monitor requests in code.  Azure Roles in the same deployment can communicate with one another in a very specific way that is not available outside of the deployment.

In Azure deployments, you need to very specifically define your public endpoint because the roles are hosted behind a load-balancer.  If you host your WCF service from within a worker-role it will not be accessible publicly.

Hope this helped

Comment: Clarification: A worker role supports both Input endpoints (visible to the outside world) and Internal endpoints (only visible within a deployment).

Comment: We do not want to go with the worker role. I am assuming the only option would be to have a secure services domain as well?

Comment: Do you want to host as two web-roles? I believe my approach also works with 2 web-roles.  Essentially, communicate between roles using non-public endpoints.  This is a solution to avoid securing your service endpoints explicitly.

Comment: Am I right in assuming that we cannot load balance internal endpoints?

Comment: @user275157 - internal endpoints are referenced by role name, not by IP address or server name, so they are load balanced.

Answer (score 1):

If you configure the WCF service and UI layer to only communicate through internal endpoints then the communication is private. There is no need to purchase or configure an SSL certificate for the WCF service unless it is made public.

Further, the only traffic between these internal endpoints will be between your instances -- so, the traffic is already restricted between your UI layer and the WCF service.

This is the case for both Web roles and worker roles: you can configure a Web role hosting your WCF service to have a private internal endpoint.

Depending on the architecture of your system you *may* see better performance if you have the UI and WCF layer on the same machine.

If your interface is "chatty" and calls the WCF service several times for each UI request then you'll definitely see a performance improvement. If there's just one or two calls then the improvement is likely to be minimal compared to the latency of your database.

Comment: I think everything in Jeremy's answer is assuming that you change your architecture to put the web site and WCF service in the same application (as two different roles).